# Gzip use short path for files and directories

Tags: bash, shell, console, compression, gzip

I am creating `gz` of all static files in build directory `dist`.

```bash
gzip -fkqr ./dist/*.html ./dist/*.css ./dist/*.js ./dist/css/*.css ./dist/js/*.js 2>/dev/null
```

Here `f` is `--force`, `k` is `--keep`, `q` is `--quiet` and `r` is `--recursive`. It is possible to make the path shorter? I tried this but not working.

```bash
gzip -fkqr ./dist/*.{html,css,js} ./dist/{css,js}/*.{css,js} 2>/dev/null
```

- Update #1

The output for `shopt | grep glob` is

```
dotglob         off
extglob         off
failglob        off
globasciiranges off
globstar        off
nocaseglob      off
nullglob        off
```

- Update #2

The output for `echo $-` is

```
himBHs
```

Comment: Please add output of `echo $-` and `shopt | grep glob` to your question.

Comment: You do not need recursive, unless you are apply gzip to directories.

Comment: Can you clarify what is `not working` with the short commands. On surface, it does compress the named.

Comment: Does `ls ./dist/*.{html,css,js} ./dist/{css,js}/*.{css,js}` show the expected output?

Comment: @MadanSapkota : Just to calrify: After running the command, you don't have any files ending in `.html.gz` in your `dist` directory, and you also don't get any error message??? What do you get if you run it with the `-v` option (verbose output)?

Comment: @MadanSapkota  can you check that you do not have .gz files ? With -k, the original files and the zip files will be left in th folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution generates more entries then you want.

```
$ echo gzip -fkqr ./dist/*.html ./dist/*.css ./dist/*.js ./dist/css/*.css ./dist/js/*.js 2>/dev/null
gzip -fkqr ./dist/*.html ./dist/*.css ./dist/*.js ./dist/css/*.css ./dist/js/*.js
$ echo gzip -fkqr ./dist/*.{html,css,js} ./dist/{css,js}/*.{css,js} 2>/dev/null
gzip -fkqr ./dist/*.html ./dist/*.css ./dist/*.js ./dist/css/*.css ./dist/css/*.js ./dist/js/*.css ./dist/js/*.js 
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I guess the `gzip` fails with `no such file or directory` kind-of message, which you don't see, because you deliberately `2>/dev/null`.

I guess you want:

```
 gzip -fkqr ./dist/*.{html,css,js} ./dist/{css/*.css,js/*.js}
```

or maybe:

```
 gzip -fkqr ./dist/{*.{html,css,js},css/*.css,js/*.js}
```